# How to Wrapped up fetch files in 1 files name modules, and export each fetch files, and import it in other components

Tags: reactjs

i have a lot of fetch that i need to wrapped it up in 1 files name modules, and then i want to use it in other components, just called the modules and the fetch name. what should i do?

i already tried using module.exports but im confused and dont know how to do it.

```
module.exports = {
    fetchLogin: require('./fetchLogin').default,
    fetchDailyStatement : require('./fetchDailyStatement').default,
    fetchOrderHistory : require('./fetchOrderHistory').default,
    fetchAccountSummary : require('./fetchAccountSummary').default
};
```

**fetchLogin.js**

```
export default {
    fetch('http://192.168.1.12:9090/orderhistory/10/25/'+ date).then(res=> res.json())
}
```

is that the right thing to do to export modules in react js ? but it still error

Comment: Do you use a custom webpack configuration or for example create-react-app?